# Left Join con Select y Where en Lambda

Tags: c#, sql

Tengo dos tablas: **encf** y **cuef**

**encf** tiene estas columnas

- numeroC
- docum
- fecha

**cuef** tiene estas columnas

- numeroC
- codigo

Tengo que realizar esta query de SQL para que por medio de un documento, se obtengan todas las filas de **encf** que tengan ese documento y todas las filas de **cuef** que tengan el mismo valor en la columna **numero** y que seleccione unicamente el valor de numero y de codigo.

Esta es la query en SQL que funciona, pero no se como pasarlo a lambda en C#:

```
SELECT 
    EF.numero,
    CF.codigo
FROM encf EF
LEFT JOIN cuef CF
ON EF.numero = CF.numero
WHERE EF.documento = 123456789
AND CF.numero IS NOT NULL
```

Y esto estuve tratando de hacer en C#:

```
var query = dc.encf.GroupJoin(
                        dc.cuef,
                        enc => enc.numero,
                        cue => cue.numero,
                        (x, y) => new { encf = x, cuef = y })
                        .SelectMany(
                        x => x.cuef.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, y) =>  new { enf = x.encf, cuef = y});
```

Problema de esa query, no selecciona unicamente **numero** y **codigo** y no filtra por un determinado **documento**. Trate varias cosas pero siempre lo rompo.

Alguna sugerencia? Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer solo te falta agregar el `where` con la respectiva validacion del numero y documento al final

Ejemplo:

```
dc.encf.GroupJoin(
    dc.cuef,
    enc => enc.numero,
    cue => cue.numero,
    (x, y) => new { encf = x, cuef = y })
    .SelectMany(
        x => x.cuef.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, y) =>  new { enf = x.encf, cuef = y})
    .Where(f => f.enf.documento = 123456789 && f.cuef!=null)
    .Select(r=> new UnionCueFor{r.enf.numero,r.cuef.codigo});//new {r.enf.numero,r.cuef.codigo}
```

Comment: Y para que seleccione unicamente numero y codigo? Cree una clase que se llama UnionCueFor y tiene dos propieades string -> numero y codigo. Como lo podría hacer que quede en eso

Comment: agrega solo Select y en esta creas un objeto con tu clase definida o solo creas un objeto anonimo con el new y ahi defines las propiedades que requieres